# Possible to ignore files in RabbitVCS via its right-click menu?

Tags: svn, ubuntu-12.04, svnignore, rabbitvcs

In Windows a tool like TortoiseSVN has `ignore file/folder` feature in its right-click menu. On Linux Ubuntu I have installed a tool called RabbitVCS, which is supposed to be the best alternative of TortoiseSVN on Linux.

However, I am unable to find `ignore` feature in its right-click menu.

Can anyone advise me on how to ignore files or folders from SVN commits using RabbitSVN tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Ignore File` menu option will existing **only if** you haven't committed the file before.

If you have committed it before, then you have to remove it from the repository first and then ignore it.